# AI created from human neural net takes over most of the population; circuit board design on the cover

Tags: story-identification

Humanity is technologically advanced. They do something; then an AI starts being created from the linking of neural nets from humans, eventually taking over most of the population by using those neural headsets. i remember the cover had a design like it was a circuit board.

Comment: You might want to check Manna, this came up in my head while reading this. But I have read it far too long ago to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a book *[A Fire upon the Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fire_Upon_the_Deep)* by Vernor Vinge.

> An expedition from Straumli Realm, an ambitious young human civilization in the high Beyond, investigates a five-billion-year-old data archive in the low Transcend that offers the possibility of unimaginable riches. The expedition's facility, High Lab, is gradually compromised by a dormant superintelligence within the archive later known as the Blight. However, shortly before the Blight's final "flowering", two self-aware entities created similarly to the Blight plot to aid the humans before the Blight can escape.
>
> Recognizing the danger of what they have awakened, the researchers at High Lab attempt to flee in two ships, one carrying all the adults and the second carrying all the children in "coldsleep boxes". Suspicious, the Blight discovers that the first ship contains a data storage device in its cargo manifest; assuming it contains information that could harm it, the Blight destroys the ship. The second ship escapes. The Blight assumes that it is no threat, but later realizes that it is actually carrying away a "countermeasure" against it.

The Blight (rogue AI) later takes over huge parts of human and non-human civilizations.

Comment: Why did this question get two downvotes? I can never understand the protocols in here

Comment: Because it doesn't give enough details about the book. He just says something about AI taking over and linking with people. It could be half of the things on this link, it really needs more details: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/HiveMind/PlayedStraight 
I put the answer just because he said "A couple years ago I read" but it could really be anything.

Comment: Or even this one: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ContagiousAI

PS: Sorry  for tvtropes links.

Comment: Ah! Getcha now - you're right, it is a bit lacking in details. Cheers